# Min-height:100% along with flexbox’s align-items: center; dont make items vertically center

Tags: html, flexbox

Before content is displayed I have a spinner that shows during 2 seconds before changing to the content itself.

Having the following Html

```
<div class=”container”>

    <div v-show ="!loading">
        //here content will be displayed after 2 seconds.
    </div>

    <div class="center" v-show="loading">
        <img  src="/default.svg" class="loading spinner-wrapper">
    </div>

</div>
<footer>
         //content
</footer>

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container
{
  //height:100%; Align items vertically center Correctly
 min-height: calc(100vh - #{$footerHeight} ); //it doesnt

}

.center

{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
 }
```

The issue is if I set the min-height:100% of the container instead of setting height:100% the spinner no longer aligns vertically to the center.

Why Im changing to min-height:100%? because The footer which is below the container is overlapping content when viewport expands or shrinks.

I have searched and I found an issue with [Explorer](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/64) .
But Im using mozilla firefox 49.0
Is there a workaround about this?

EDIT.
 My markup works fine. the problem is the flexbox align Items.
look this [article](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html). It is the same.
EDIT2.
On chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) the issue is also present. BUT if it is me who is making something wrong WHY height:100% makes items align center correctly?

Comment: I upvoted this just because you used the right tag :)

Comment: Actually, I have been doing tests, and it seems when you set min-height:100% its like items inside it dont understand they have plenty of space to align. If i hardcode the height to 1000px it starts working again. Btw  @Brian thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Have you tried `height:100vh;` or `vertical-align`?

Comment: @wrldbt I have right now. Same result.

Comment: The flexing occurs on the items, so making your image a flex item and telling it to center on a non-flex container won't get the result you're looking for. Here is a jsbin converting the container to a flex and then aligning the item as expected: http://jsbin.com/lewefiyaxi/edit?html,css,output - I'd probably opt for a different solution to how your placing your loader by not making it an item personally as when your content is inject you'll force a layout invalidation on the flex which is undesirable. You'll want to possibly just do a paint change if possible.

Comment: thank you @gregwhitworth That is the answer. Please turn it so I can accept it.

Comment: But... Making the container to display flex will make all the items to display flex. If I would like just a portion of the code to display flex, not the entire container???? Because your solution only will work if the place where I set the min-height:100% also displays flex.

Comment: I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self align self property which will override the General Center Condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flexing occurs on the items, so making your image a flex item and telling it to center on a non-flex container won't get the result you're looking for. Here is a jsbin converting the container to a flex and then aligning the item as expected: jsbin.com/lewefiyaxi/edit?html,css,output - I'd probably opt for a different solution to how your placing your loader by not making it an item as when your content is injected you'll force a layout invalidation on the flex which is undesirable. You'll want to possibly just do a paint change if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here:

- Using ***chrome***, if a container has **min_height and
  display:flex**; the items inside it will not change adding
  **align-items:center**; while it works by giving a fixed height.
- Using ***firefox*** the problem does not arise.

Is there a possibility to center elements vertically in chrome when the
container has a min-height and flexbox?

```
// **HTML**  

 <form>
          <!--  DIFFICULTY FIELDSET  -->
          <fieldset class="container container_difficulty">
            <legend>Difficulty</legend>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" id="easy" name="difficulty" value="easy">
              <label class="button" for="easy">Easy</label>                  
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" id="medium" name="difficulty" value="medium" checked> 
              <label class="button" for="medium">Medium</label>                                 
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" id="hard" name="difficulty" value="hard">
              <label class="button" for="hard">Hard</label>                  
            </div>
          </fieldset>
</form>
    
// **CSS**

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;

  background-color: hsla(242, 50%, 0%, 0.259);
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.18);
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 hsla(236, 19%, 48%, 0.249);
}
.button{  
  cursor: pointer;

  background-color: #23020e;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px hsla(300, 100%, 50%, 0.612);

  transition: all .15s linear;
}

form{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

fieldset.container{
  min-width: 48%;

  align-items: center;
  min-height: 20vh; //Works in firefox. In chrome height: 20vh solve the issue

  gap: .5rem;
  margin: 1.5em .5em;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2em;
  
}

fieldset.container label{
  display: block;
  width: 6em;
  padding: .5em .8em;
  font-size: .9em;
}

input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}
```

[Chrome vs Firefox display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jip7d.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).